# Delay textbox-textchanged in vb

Tags: vb.net, timer, delay, intervals

I am  a simple beginner  and need small help:
I have textbox1 and textbox2.
Supposed when you put a number (for ex. 21) in the textbox1, I need  textbox2 to give me the double number (42). I mean that I need `textbox2.text=2*textbox1.text`

I used this simple code :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Textlength(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
         TextBox2.Text = 2*TextBox1.Text
```

The problem is: when I wrote (in textbo1) only one digit everything it's ok, but I could not write two (or more) digits.
How do I make a delay (interval) which allows me to type a number like (1990 for example) before firing textbox1_changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextChanged fires every time you change the content of the textbox. So there is no way to block this behavior. Perhaps you could add a button and move the recalculation on the button click event or better add an event handler for [the Validating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx).
This event is triggered when you exit from the control and you have also the option to check the input and block the exiting from the TextBox control

```
Private Sub textBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim v as Integer
    if Not Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, v) Then
         e.Cancel = True
         MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number")
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = (v * 2).ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Notice that when you handle the user input expecting a numeric value you should apply particular attention because you don't know what the user types. In this case the [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be the appropriate approach.

Another suggestion is to enable immediately the [**Option Strict ON**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) in your project, the default is OFF and this allows very dangerous code like treating a string like it was a number.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. Just allow the TextChanged event to fire every time, and the second text box will always display twice the value of the first one, so when 1 is entered, it will show 2, when the 9 is added, it will show 38, and so on. You should of course address Steve's concerns about validation, and implied type conversions.